# Recv failure : Connection was reset git

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

Background: My company has self-hosted GitLab which can only be accessed when connected via Wireguard VPN. I have setup VPN and am able to access the company's GitLab via browser successfully.

Problem: But when I try to clone a repo I get "fatal: unable to access xxx : Recv failure : Connection was reset, git " . I have also enabled git trace to debug it and here are the results
[image]

Even when I try to push to a newly created empty repo on gitlab , I get the same error :
[image]

I have tried various solution like unsetting proxy etc but I am unable to resolve this. I am really stuck to this error, plz help

Answer (score 3):

You can try this! step by step!

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: Hi @csy100, welcome to the stack overflow. Could you describe how the above commands would sole the OP question?

Comment: I would also like a more detailed explanation.  However, this did solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Since there can probably be many causes, I can only help you by posting what solved my problem:

I looked at changing the port from 20 to 443, to setting a config file etc, but in the end what worked for me was **I basically had to change the `http` in the url to `https`** and then I could clone etc.

`httpS://gitlab.yourcompany.com/folder_name/your_project.git`